# reference interface by creating object in java

Tags: java

Is it possible that one class access the method from another class by using the interface reference??

Suppose, i have a class that is `loginUIController.java`, from this class i want to access method of another class that is `mainController.java`. But I won't access the method directly. for accessing method from `mainController.java` i'll use the Interface of `mainController.java` which is `InferfaceMainController.java`.

The following classes are :-

Here is the `loginUIController.java`

```
public class LoginUIController
{
       InterfaceMainController mainController = null;

  private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException 
  {
       String userid = txt_username.getText();
       String password = txt_password.getText();

       mainController.checkLogin(userid, password);   
  }
}
```

InterfaceMainController :-

```
public interface InterfaceMainController {

    void checkLogin(String userid, String password);
    void addContact(String name, String phone, String address, String email);  
}
```

mainController :-

```
public class MainController implements InterfaceMainController{

    @Override
    public void checkLogin(String userid, String password){
        Users u = new Users();
        u.setUserid(userid);
        u.setPassword(password);
        DBLayer db1 = new DBLayer();

        try 
        {
          if(db1.userExists(u))
          {
              System.out.println("login Success.");
          }
          else
          {
              System.out.println("login Failed.");
          }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, how to access `checkLogin(String userid, String password);`of `mainController.java` from the `loginUIController.java` by creating the interface object of `InterfaceMainController.java`?

Comment: Looks like Dependency Injection. Try that.

Comment: how i use dependency injection in here? @Elliott Frisch

Comment: that's not fact, i have explained it in short...please try to my question. -Ramanlfc

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You have to instantiate an implementation of the interface *somewhere*, and either pass it in, have it instantiated by any DI/IoC mechanism, or in the class where you need it.

Comment: here, my uncompleted code, i want to access method of mainController.java from loginUIController.java through using an interface object reference. so, now how i can do it. @Dave Newton

Comment: By instantiating an implementation of the interface and using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the point of view of `LoginUIController`, there's no such thing as `MainController`. `LoginUIController` only *knows* about `InterfaceMainController`. That's essentially what you defined in:

```
InterfaceMainController mainController = null;
```

To work with an instance of `InterfaceMainController` you first need an implementation of the interface, which in your case is `MainController`. Then, you create an instance of the implementation:

```
InterfaceMainController mainController = new MainController();
```

Finally, you need to provide the instance to whatever needs it, in your case `LoginUIController`. A common way to do this is to create a constructor like so:

```
public class LoginUIController
{
    InterfaceMainController mainController = null;

    public LoginUIController(InterfaceMainController mainController) {
        this.mainController = mainController
    }  
    ...
}
```

The above is an example of the *dependency injection* Elliot referenced.

Comment: Very nice example of constructor based dependency injection.

Comment: yeah, your answer is correct . thank you @ElliottFrisch

Comment: would you give me any web link for learning advanced concept of java??@ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a difference in how you do it. It's really the handle you have.

```
InterfaceMainController foo = new MainController();

foo.checkLogin("me", "my password");
```

You can pass foo to any method that expects an InterfaceMainController. But the code otherwise looks the same. It's only the variable type that changes.

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippets, it appears you are missing one object which implements the interface `InterfaceMainController` (in your example this would be an instance of `MainController`).  I can think of two options to remedy this:

1. Pass the object to the constructor of LoginUIController.
2. Use Inversion of Control (IOC) / Dependency Injection.

Option #1 is ok so far as it goes, but in such an approach you would be responsible for object lifecycle and ownership.  Option #2 is not a Java language feature, but rather something provided by Frameworks, eg [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to pass `MainController` obj to `InterfaceMainController` reference variable.

Without Spring

```
InterfaceMainController mainController = new MainController();
```

Using Spring annotation

If you are using spring then you can use annotations to auto wire the `MainController` object with `@component` and `@Autowired`  something like this

```
@Component  
public class MainController implements InterfaceMainController {
  ........
}
```

and auto wire `mainController` with annotation `@Autowired` like this

```
@Autowired  
InterfaceMainController mainController
```